Continuity implies surjectivity if the the limits in both infinities are infinite
I'm trying to show the following:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and such that


$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$
$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$


Under these conditions, $f$ is surjective.
I study alone and, therefore, I have no way of knowing, most of the time, if what I'm doing is right. I appreciate anyone who can help me.
My demonstration attempt
My attempt, in short, consists of restricting the function $f$ to any closed interval $[-x',+x']$.
According to the intermediate value theorem, $f$ takes on all values ​​between $f(-x')$ and $f(+x')$. As the limits, in both infinities, are infinite,

$\small{\text{$-\infty$, for $x$ increasingly negative}};$
$\small{\text{$+\infty$, for $x$ increasingly positive}};$

we have that there will always be a $L$, belonging to the image of the function, such that $f$ is smaller than $-L$ or larger than $+L$.
Now, what I think is fundamental: when defining a limit, we say that the value $L$ is ARBITRARY AND ANY — for all $L>0$, there is $M>0$, such that... —. Therefore, it will always be possible to restrict the function $f$ to any closed interval, so that $f$ assumes all values, in the set of images, between $f(-x')$ and $f(+x')$ and, thus, $f$ is surjective in $\mathbb{R}$.

Hi and welcome to Math Stackexchange. What's your question? We don't do full-proof checking on this site.

Hello, Mr. Ben Steffan. I did not know that it was not allowed to ask this type of question here, on this platform (I should have dedicated more time to reading the rules of this site) and, for this, I sincerely apologize. Would you mind telling me why this type of questioning is not allowed? I just want to understand why. I hope I have been polite and educated in this reply. Thank you very much. @BenSteffan

It's ok, no need to be this formal :) We generally don't allow questions like this to prevent the site being flooded by people trying to get their homework checked. You can still ask questions about proofs, but you do have to identify (a) certain step(s) or doubt(s) and why you're not sure, generally speaking. To quote from the solution-verification tag description: '"Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.'

I understand what you mean, my friend. In fact, I did not indicate where my distrust appeared. Next time, I will be explicit in pointing out the argumentative step that I do not feel confident about.
Rest assured that my intentions here, on this forum, are serious. Don't worry, I'll never ask for a complete solution for me, but always asking for tips, after trying a lot on my own, always explaining what I tried to do.
Thanks for the kind reply.

By the way, to show my good intentions towards the time of the people on this forum and valuing its immeasurable usefulness - always taking into account the name of MathStackExchange and trying not to pollute it with simplistic questions (those that a typical student of Calculation would do) - I took the attitude/freedom of putting together a new demonstration attempt using some different ideas and principles. I know I've already accepted the answer below as the chosen answer, but with all that said, would you,
guys, like to discuss my new point of view here, in this comment box?

@cambridgecircus

By the way, if you just click on the tag "solution-verification", you can see a general description of what is acceptable in a question with that tag.

@LeeMosher Got it!

A pretty straightforward proof can show what you're after. Note that $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$:

$\exists x_1$ such that $f(x_1)<a$. This is because if $\forall x, f(x)>a$, then we can't have $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$
Similarly note $\exists x_2$ such that $f(x_2)>a$.
The IVT says that $\exists x_3\in[x_1,x_2]$ or $\exists x_3\in[x_2,x_1]$ such that $f(x_3)=a$.

Hence $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}, \exists x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=a$.

What a lovely, charming, elegant and sophisticated proof, sir @cambridgecircus. It is simple to understand and objective, qualities that all well-done Mathematics must have. I thank you for helping me. However, could you tell me if my attempted demonstration is correct (or, at least, has the minimally necessary traces of argumentation and reasoning to be able to benefit from it)? If not, could you tell me where I was misleading or wrote an obscure passage? Thank you very much.
